# Can Clone be used to create a "fake" body?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

I'm setting up the Big Bad for my D&D campaign, and for the setup to work the players need to believe that one of their trusted allies and mentor is has been killed, because this trusted ally is actually the Big Bad.

So my solution is that the Big Bad creates a clone body of herself using the 8th level Necromancy spell "Clone". The spell description doesn't say anything about removing the clone body from the vessel in which it was grown, so I'm assuming that if she was to do that, the clone would basically just be a soulless meat copy of herself.

I guess I want to know if there are any rules that contradict this scenario. Can the clone just be taken out of the vessel and used as a "fake body" with no repercussions on the person who was cloned?

NOTE: the players are 1st level and don't have access to any magic that could be used to speak with dead, or otherwise interact with the dead clone body.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

### RAW, Yes.

> grows to full size and maturity after 120 days... It remains inert and endures indefinitely, as long as its vessel remains undisturbed.

That means disturbing the vessel would result in a fully grown meat copy which the soul could no longer transfer to. So, your reading agrees with my understanding of the Rules as they are Written. It does seem that disturbing the vessel will prevent the clone body from being used in the designed way, but that isn't your intent anyway.

Answer (score 6):

#### Yes, but also...

> At any time after the clone matures, if the original creature dies, its soul transfers to the clone, provided that the soul is free and willing to return.

If the big bad wanted to be killed in front of the party (and was confident in the spell), he could just hire someone to kill him. Then there are witnesses, a body, and an alive bad guy.

Comment: Very interesting idea, and IMO a better one than just leaving a body on the floor. It would be much more convincing for players to see their mentor die in front of them, maybe during a fight against the "BB troupes".